# Can I have the params with an empty object with getStaticPaths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

In the getStaticPaths function, there is a path returned with params postId:1. If have two or three more params with postId: 2, postId: 3 etc. those will be statically generated. Right?

Is there a way not to statically load any post with any id? If I want to load all the posts with
the loading screen, is that can be made possible?

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router"

export default function Post({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h4>{post.id} - {post.title}</h4>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
       {
         params: { postId: "1" }
       }
     ],                 
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.postId}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if(!data.id) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      post: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a solution to fetch dynamic data for a static page instead of serving a fallback page from static-side generation.

I'd propose 2 options:

You can use server-side rendering with [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props). Of course, all HTML will be generated during run-time (HTML generation per request)

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.postId}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if(!data.id) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      post: data,
    },
  };
}
```

The second option is [Incremental static regeneration (ISR)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) (available from version 9.5). This is the upgrade version of static-site generation (SSG) and likely a hybrid between SSG and SSR, it will generate all static HTML with defined paths in `getStaticPath` (like SSG), BUT if the path, which a user has fetched, is not defined, it will automatically generate HTML on the fly, and then cache it on the server (like other generated HTMLs in SSG). To have this behavior, you need to use `fallback: 'blocking'` in `getStaticPaths` (If you want to understand how `fallback` works, you can check [this document](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#getstaticpaths-return-values) out)

ISR is also providing a revalidation mechanism. You can set the timer for updating your generated HTML due to API's data update. The only downside of this feature is that is only available from [Next.js 12.1](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-1), so you can consider upgrading your Next.js version for this implementation.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
       {
         params: { postId: "1" }
       }
     ],                 
    fallback: "blocking", //Next.js 9.5 - generate a new HTML based on user demand if the path is not defined
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${params.postId}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();

  if(!data.id) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {
      post: data,
    },
    revalidate: 10, //Next.js 12.1 - Validate data to regenerate static HTMLs every 10 seconds
  };
}
```

Comment: So, I'll need to use SSR or ISR. Understood. But, can you please tell be what you meant when you said: ```fallback: blocking // generate a new path based on user demand ``` Isn't it supposed to be for the functionality where we don't want the loading page to be showed?

Comment: Actually, I should rephrase `generate a static HTML with a non-defined path`. ISR is like a hybrid between SSR and SSG. It will help you to generate a new HTML during run-time with a non-defined path and cache it for later usage. You can check [this doc](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration) out for a better understanding

Comment: _"if the path, which a user has fetched, is not defined, it will automatically generate HTML on the fly"_ - probably worth mentioning this behaviour only happens when `fallback` is `true` or `'blocking'`.

Comment: `fallback: true` is still serving the fallback page though, but we want to generate a page instead of a fallback page, @juliomalves

Comment: `fallback: true` will initially serve a fallback while the page gets generated on the server. My point was, `fallback: false` does not generate new pages not created at build time.